# How to interpret delete rule in Core data in XCode?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

I have example as it is on the image below:
[image]

How should I understand this?

What happen to `PBOLocation` when I delete `PBORole`? **or**
What happen to `PBORole` when I remove `PBOLocation`? **or**
What happen to `PBORole` when I remove relationship between them? **or**
What happen to `PBOLocation` when I remove relationship between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your delete rule in the image is `Nullify`. Therefore, "nothing" will happen.

When you delete `Role`, `location.roles` will be reduced by one.
When you delete `Location`, `role.location` will be `nil`.
When you you remove the relationship by setting `role.location = nil`, `location.roles` will be reduced by one.
When you reduce a `role` from `location.roles`, `role.location` will be `nil`.

If, however you choose `Cascade` as the delete rule, it becomes more interesting:

When you remove the relationship from either direction, the same happens as described above.
If you set the `Cascade` rule for the `roles` relationship on `Location`, deleting `Location` will delete all `Role` objects in `roles`.
If you set the `Cascade` rule for the `location` in `Role`, deleting `Role` will delete its `location` (and if the reverse relationship rule is `Cascade` as in the rule above, all other `roles` will be deleted as well).

Read all about it in the Core Data Programming Guide under [Relationship Delete Rules](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001857-SW1).